# Where is the man page for "pthread_mutex_lock"?

Tags: package-management

I can't find the manual for `pthread_mutex_lock` with `man pthread_mutex_lock`, is that something wrong with `manpages-dev` ? I got that package installed, but missing some manual.

Should I fire a bug to Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation for pthreads is in the [glibc-doc](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/glibc-doc) package.

Comment: Note that (as of 19.04 Disco Dingo) `glibc-doc` includes the Linux-specific man pages for pthreads, whereas the `manpages-posix-dev` package has the POSIX pthreads man pages

Comment: @villapx Do you have an idea why some of the Linux-specific man pages for pthread, that is the one including implementation concerns of the pthread API, still refer to LinuxThreads and not NTPL  as can be seen for example here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3.html ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva Great question, I'm not sure. I'm doing some digging at the moment to try and find out why. It doesn't look like the NPTL implementation is descended from LinuxThreads (looking at Wikipedia. etc.), but maybe they did inherit some of the man pages because they were well written?

Comment: @villapx maybe yes teh writing style is a motivation. I'll probably ask a separate question, but int the cas of cond_wait this makes a big difference since the glibc-doc does not mention spurious wake-up at all.

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu (and Debian) include the desired man pages in the `manpages-posix-dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here a version we can enjoy in our web-browser:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3.html

I know, links might get outdated, but if we feed our search-engine we will get a lot of alternative links which deliver the desired information.

**Advantage**: Better readability, comfortability with use in GUI. We don't need to install anything.

**Disadvantage:** Requires Internet connection (at least for the time we need to download the site).

Answer (score 1):

Just install the glibc-doc package, the missing man pages will be there:

```
sudo apt install glibc-doc
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer posted in July 2012? 

Comment: I actually thought he was just linking to the site of the package. So I thought it better to add the script to install it. But now I clicked on the link and discovered it was a script for installing the package, and not a link to site. So you are correct, apparently it's not different.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev 
man pthread_mutex_lock(/unlock/destroy/...)
```

You can see the result ... thank you

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  Could you explain why you think this will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For KDE Neon, I was able to find everything with:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev
sudo apt-get install glibc-doc
```

I needed the second to find things like man pthread_mutex_unlock