# "No manual entry for pthread" - could not find man page by name

Tags: package-management, documentation, manpage

I am new to Ubuntu, wanted to code for reader-writer block in Operating System, but when I fired the command `man pthread` it gave me an error **no manual entry for pthread**. What can be done to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First install these manpages:

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev
```

and then:

```
man pthreads
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is one of those things you've just got to know?

Comment: or `sudo apt install glibc-doc`, since the `glibc-doc` package should include [Linux-specific man pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167521/where-is-the-man-page-for-pthread-mutex-lock#comment1939623_167524)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the man page you look for is not there:

```
$ man pthread
No manual entry for pthread
```

Hmm... let's look for something similar!
We will se `man` option `-k` for that:

```
$ man -k pthread 
pthread_attr_destroy (3) - initialize and destroy thread attributes object
pthread_attr_getaffinity_np (3) - set/get CPU affinity attribute in thread attributes object
pthread_attr_getdetachstate (3) - set/get detach state attribute in thread attributes object
pthread_attr_getguardsize (3) - set/get guard size attribute in thread attributes object
[... 47 more lines ...]
pthread_timedjoin_np (3) - try to join with a terminated thread
pthread_tryjoin_np (3) - try to join with a terminated thread
pthread_yield (3)    - yield the processor
pthreads (7)         - POSIX threads
vfs_aio_pthread (8)  - implement async I/O in Samba vfs using a pthread pool
```

Ok... some related stuff... Oh! `pthreads` looks interesting!

```
$ man pthreads|head -n 12
PTHREADS(7)           Linux Programmer's Manual          PTHREADS(7)



NAME
       pthreads - POSIX threads

DESCRIPTION
       POSIX.1  specifies  a  set  of  interfaces (functions, header
       files) for  threaded  programming  commonly  known  as  POSIX
       threads,  or Pthreads.  A single process can contain multiple
       threads, all of which are executing the same program.   These
```

Now, looks like we found it!

Answer (score 1):

Even if we have installed related man packages, we may still suffer "No manual entry for pthread".

On ubuntu, we should use

> man pthread**s**  (note the bold **s**)

instead of

> man pthread